# How to avoid page refreshing after if condition execution

Tags: javascript, if-statement, reload

I have written a if condition in javascript, the problem is that , if the condition is true, the statement (alert box) is executing, if I click the OK button in alert box the entire web page is reloading, and the values selected in each control is going back to the old state. The code is below. I tried "return true" , but its not working.

```
if(fromvalue==="" || tovalue1==="")
    {
        alert('Kindly select the origin and destination');
        return true;

    }



    else if(departuredate==="" || returndate==="")
    {
        alert('Kindly select the departure and return date');

    }
      else if(infantcountvalue>adultcountvalue)
    {
        alert("the infant number should be equal to or less than adult");

    }
    else if(departureday>returnday)
    {
        alert('Return date should be after the departure date');

    }

    else if(totalpassenger>9)
    {
        alert("Maximum 9 passengers are allowed.");


    }
    else   
    { 


         window.open(StrQueryString);
             // submitform();



    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code too. I bet you're working with a form and that, once you submit it, you're not preventing the default action of the submit button, which is going to submit the page regardless the if else conditions.

Comment: Console.log() to narrow down what is causing that, since alert and return true; wont refresh the page.

Comment: here is the HTML for submit button                                                                      <div class="clear">
                                            <input type="submit" id="flightsearchboxid" onclick="flightsearch()"  class="login" value="SEARCH" /> 
                                     </div>

Comment: change the submit into a regular button, I mean, just do this: `<input type="button" id="flightsearchboxid" onClick="flightsearch()" class="login" value="SEARCH" />` and you're done. However, please remember that instead of window.open you should rather SUBMIT the form, else every value sent will be lost. You should post us the entire HTML anyway ;)